# What are the Rules of Hidden Club?

Tags: dnd-4e, stealth

I'm playing a rogue in a 4th edition game.  It hasn't come up yet, but I'm pretty sure that I'm going to need to hide, possibly in combat, at some point in the near future.  I'm aware that there are a series of rules about hiding in 4th edition referred to as The Rules of Hidden Club, but I've never seen them, and don't really know what I'm looking for.

How exactly does hiding work in 4th edition, and what are the Rules of Hidden Club?

Comment: "I've never seen them, and don't really know what I'm looking for" - well, they *are* Hidden Club!

Comment: I thought we must already have a question for this, but looks like we don't! All the more useful now that the original has lost its home.

Comment: Related: [When a creature is invisible, but not hidden, do the enemies know the location of the creature?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/4828) (and I fixed the URL in one of the answers)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a Google search for "The Rules of Hidden Club," I found [the document you're looking for](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?447238-The-Rules-of-Hidden-Club-I-Think-I-Failed-A-Spot-Check) as the first result.

It's essentially an explanation of the rules for the Stealth skill (found in the Rules Compendium or on the Compendium website) with a guide to applying them wisely.

The basics, heavily summarized, are:

> The First Rule Of Hidden Club: **Stay out of sight.** If, at ANY TIME, you lack at least Cover or Concealment from an enemy, you lose Hidden against that enemy.
>
> The Second Rule Of Hidden Club: **Keep quiet.**
>
> The Third Rule Of Hidden Club: **Keep Still.** If you don't move more than 2 squares at a time, you have no chance of losing Hidden.
>
> The Fourth Rule Of Hidden Club: **Don't Attack.** If you attack, you are immediately Expelled From Hidden Club, period.
>
> The Fifth Rule Of Hidden Club: **Don't let the enemy FIND you.**
>
> The Unspeakable Final Rule Of Hidden Club: When you do something to lose Hidden, you keep the benefits of being Hidden until the end of that action.